# python test compare 2 objects of the same class

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, equality, nose

In a test, I need to compare that 2 objects of a class have the same values for each of the class attributes. I do not need to compare 2 objects of the class outside of my testing.

Is it better to implement the **eq** in my class (even though the production code does not need it), or is it better to just compare the **dict** of each object in my test? Like this:

```
assert_equals(obj1.__dict__, obj2.__dict__)
```

If I implement it in the class, then I can just say:

```
assert_equals(obj1, obj2)
```

Comment: IMO implementing `__eq__` would definitely make things clearer - `obj1 == obj1` is better than e.g. `obj1.equals(obj2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both will work of course, but I'd recommend implementing `__eq__` because:

1. It's low cost / doesn't take very much work
2. Your tests will be easier to read if you're returning to them at some point in the future (or if someone else has to work with them)
3. It's good future-proofing: the `__eq__` method can be inherited, and if you've already had need to assess equality in a test, then you never know - your production code may well require this feature in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` and inheritance don't play well together in this regard. If you want to compare something and really be sure that the comparison makes sense, then I would say implement **eq** or **cmp** on the class.

Comment: Thanks, my class does not use inheritance, but then you never know what might happen in the future!